# Real time date is not reflecting on google analytics dashboard for (android app) from last 5 days

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

We have not made any changes to the code and suddenly, real-time report data on google analytics has stopped working

Comment: There isnt enough information here to help you.  The real time reports only work for 5 minutes.

Comment: I am not able to see the count of active users who are currently using my application .

Comment: I am not able to see the count of active users who are currently using my application .